# Install wine application launchers in /usr/share/applications instead than /root/.local/share/applications

Tags: wine, 22.04, sudo, .desktop

When I first run a Windows application installer using wine without the sudo command, the application launchers of the installed program go to `~/.local/share/applications` while the wine path goes to `~/.wine`. With sudo I expected them to go to `/usr/share/applications` and instead, to my bitter surprise they go to `/root/.local/share/applications` while the wine path goes to the correct path `/etc/wine`.
How do I change the default path of the wine application launchers to `/usr/share/applications` when I first run a Windows application installer with the sudo command?

Comment: Why did you run with SUDO?

Comment: Because I want the wine programs installed globally and accessible from the launcher like any other program.

Comment: As far as I know you never run Wine install as Root or with Sudo.

Comment: @David `As far as I know you never run Wine install as Root or with Sudo` This is exactly what I did instead, explained in a way that was even redundant in the question.